# Isabelle/Simpl: Type unification failed using hoarestate

Tags: isabelle

I started using Isabelle/Simpl and write the following theory according to the user guide:

```
theory Scratch
  imports Simpl.Simpl
begin

hoarestate newvars =
  N :: nat

lemma (in newvars) "Γ ⊢ {} ´N :== ´N + 1 {}"
  sorry
end
```

But Isabelle complains that type unification fails:

```
Type unification failed

Type error in application: operator not of function type

Operator:  N_' :: 'a
Operand:   s :: ??'a
```

Simpl itself (including its user guide) successfully compiles.
How can I make it pass?

Comment: I'm not an expert in Isabelle/Simpl, but you can make your example pass by importing `Simpl.Vcg` instead of `Simpl.Simpl`.

Answer (score 0):

As [Javier Díaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12984990/javier-d%c3%adaz) pointed out, importing only `Simpl.Vcg` instead of `Simpl.Simpl` does the trick.

The cause of the error seems a name collision against a record defined in `Simpl.SyntaxTest`. It contains the following record definition:

```
record 'g vars = "'g state" +
  A_' :: "nat list"
  AA_' :: "nat list list"
  I_' :: nat
  M_' :: nat
  N_' :: nat
  R_' :: int
  S_' :: int
  B_' :: bool
  Abr_':: string
  p_' :: ref
  q_' :: ref
```

Isabelle seems to prefer `N_'` in the record to `N` in the hoarestate, although the hoarestate is defined later. I don't know why this is the case.